# Run-time Error '32809' and Active X controls changed name

Tags: vba, excel

Huge problem here. I sent an excel form (a workbook with several sheets, thousands of active x controls and many many macros) to several people that they need to fill and return to me. Only one of the completed form I received is now completely impossible to use. All active X controls have changed name. If I select one I see the old name, but if I click on it the macro doesn't start and if I try to see its code it opens a new empty Macro with the new control name_click (Ex: a button called cmd_button1 opens a Macro called cmd_button2_click). When I start the Macro in VBA, I get the Run-time Error '32809' every time the code wants to unprotect sheets or to change the visible value of a sheet.

I looked on other posts and every solution I found would require a huge amount of work. What happened? Is there an easy solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Thousands of ActiveX controls?

Comment: MrTryHard, great name!... ahem. First try Debug > Compile... . Also CUT all the code in notebook, then save close and open the project, then paste it back in to the modules. Long shot options.

Comment: Lynn: hundreds for sure.

Comment: pnuts: I would have to transfer all their answers. It was my final option but that doesn't prevent it from happening again and it gives me no understanding of the problem.

Comment: Gary: I will try this tomorow. Any idea why it happened?

Comment: @GaryEvans I saved the workbook in xlsx and copy/pasted all my macros, transfered the forms and modules back then savec it back to xlsm and now the buttons call the macros (which is pretty much what you suggested). It works now, so thanks a lot for your help. Do you think it happened because the user was not using the same version of excel as me?

Comment: You'll find people will advise to not code while debugging, I.e. don't use F8 and write/fix the code as you go because this can cause odd behaviour, for example it can leave a ghost break point where there is no break point. When it happened to me this is what I done to 'fix' the VBA storage area (its not called that but I can't think of a better way to describe it). But the version thing could be the issue too. Could you write up the details of how you fixed it as the answer? it could help people in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the workbook in .xlsx and copy/pasted all my macros back, transfered the forms and modules back then saved it back to .xlsm and now the buttons call the macros and no run time errors occur anymore.